# Excel with Reporting Services via WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, excel, reporting-services

What is the best way of using Excel as the client for reporting services via WCF?

I would like to do something along the lines of Excel calling a WCF service which sends back the URL of where the report is on the reporting server and then displays it.

How would I go about this? What excel add-on, if any, do I need and how can I make Excel aware of my WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a tutorial](http://damianblog.com/2009/07/05/excel-wcf/) that may be what others in the future may be looking for.